# Issues in google rankings

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have a new site just over 6 months old and after a month or so, it started ranking for some searches in Google.

Then suddenly after 2 months, boom, no traffic coming from search other than when people search for the name of the site.

My question is whether this is something common? I was doing some link-building, forums,blogs,social bookmarks,directory submission.

This affects whole website or any new updates in seo

Answer (score 1):

`I was doing some link-building, forums,blogs,social bookmarks,directory submission` <-- that's most likely your problem, you've been hit by [Google's evil penguin](http://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) and yes it's very common for those who create links themselves as Google regards this as attempting to manipulate search results.

*Non Relevant Links*

Google now punishes sites for links from non-relevant sites on a big scale, these include but not limited to, forums reply's, forums signatures, blog comments, low quality social bookmarking sites i.e pligg, directory sites etc etc. Lot's of [questions and answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=penguin) regarding penguin on the site.

*Unpunished Sites*

You should also note that most recently millions of sites that were affected by Penguin have had their punishments lifted, so you might not be affected much so to speak but rather that people have got their rankings back and knocking you down.

Comment: iam using some high pr backlinks only,so this will also to affect sites.

Comment: PR Backlinks is oldschool SEO and unless those links are relevant to the content linking too they won't help as much as you think and enough of those links even if they are HIGH PR will harm you....

Comment: E.G getting a link from Adobe PR 9 linking to your site about 'cats' is not going to help your SEO, and enough `irrelevant` links Google will slap your site. Unless you have a link from a page about Cats on the adobe site. I recommend you read quality SEO guides dated 2013, and 2014 from quality websites such as MOZ.

Answer (score 0):

Building back-links from irrelevant contents will degrade your website reputation and content reliability. Do not try to build backlinks. Do concentrate on providing good are reliable contents. Backlinks will automatically come.